# Xcode debugger doesn't show class-wide variables

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging

I know the question has already been asked, but I didn't find any convincing explanation.

In the code below, `a` is a class-wide variable and `c` a function-wide variable.

```
class TestClass {
    var a, b: Int

    init()
    {
        var c: Int

        a = 1
        c = 1
        b = 2 // --> Breakpoint
    }
}
```

Why does the debugger only display the content of `c` and not `a` or `b`?

Can check either by hovering the mouse over each variable, or by looking in the debugger variables:

[image: Xcode debugger screenshot]

Comment: Not sure why the answer was downvoted, but have you tried expanding `self`? You should see the other two variables there. (Because your breakpoint is on the line that sets `b`, you'll find the value is defaulted to 0.)

Comment: EDIT: Both a and b *are* class wide, but by default the line of code you set your breakpoint on will display only locally-scoped variables. I assumed you know that `self` refers to the class object where your breakpoint is set. Also, assuming you are instantiating `TestClass` from another object - say, `ViewController` - you will not see any variables from that class.

Comment: Thanks dfd. "but by default the line of code you set your breakpoint on will display only locally-scoped variables" -> why only local ones and not class-wide ? Is this a setting I can change in XCode ?

Comment: I honestly don't know! I just became used to expanding `self`, understanding that that's how Xcode operates. (Been using it since 2004, but only since 2016 as my main IDE.) I'm *very* sure that some coders who use Xcode might have ways to make it show without the need to use one more tap/click. (Last side note - you should work with SAP - now *that* is a horrendous platform to code in.)